# How can I get a Django TemplateLoader see the current Context or Request?

Tags: django, django-templates, request

I' m trying to build a Django TemplateLoader, but I can't make it 'see' either the current Context or Request, so I can't really do much with it.

Does anyone know how I can make a Django TemplateLoader do this?

Many Thanks

Joe

Comment: More information needed. Why does it need access to the request or the context? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to achieve a TemplateLoader where it can dynamically decide wether to load a template from the mobile folder or wherever.

I know there is ways to make this work by using stuff like making a render_to_response alternative, but I don't want to do this as I want to be able to include mobile versions of templates on a standart page.

Hope it makes sense :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The place to make decisions about templates is in your view. There, you have access to the request, and can dynamically construct a template name depending on whatever conditions you like. E.g.,

```
def my_view(request, ...):
  ...
  template_name = 'template.html'
  if is_mobile(request): template_name = 'mobile_' + template_name
  template = get_template(template_name)
  context = RequestContext(request, {...})
  return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

Where you provide the `is_mobile()`. Better would be to provide a method that takes a request and template name, and returns one appropriately modified (so that you can encode that logic once, rather than scattering across several views).

You might also get some leverage from [select_template()](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django.template.loader.select_template), which takes a list of candidate template names, returning a template for the first one it finds.

Comment: yeah i have something similar currently in place as a replacement render_to_response (called template), but how do I apply that to things like
django.contrib.auth.views.login as they use the proper render_to_response

Comment: You don't need to invoke django.contrib.auth.views.login directly from a urlpattern. You can wrap it an other view that uses the request to figure out what template_name to pass it.

Comment: Oh okay. I will look at doing that then. Thanks very much :)